# Retrieve monitoring logs of Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I have created a Traffic Manager in Azure Portal and added a couple of AppService as an endpoint.

I want to monitor the status of the Traffic Manager to track below scenarios:

1. To track when the Traffic Manager is Inactive or any other state other than Online.
2. To generate logs when the Traffic Manager is Inactive.
3. To monitor which AppService is Online and which is Inactive/Degraded.
4. Also want to track how many requests have been made to the Traffic Manager, i.e hit count to traffic manager DNS.

Is there any way to enable logging for monitoring the status?[image]

Any help, highly appreciated..

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to enable logging for monitoring the status?

Azure provides the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/trafficmanager/profiles#Profiles_Get) that could be used to get the info of Traffic Manager profile. If possible, you could try to write a program by calling this REST API and extract the status info of Traffic Manager profile and endpoints from the response, and you could run your program on schedule to monitor the status of the Traffic Manager and generate logs.

[image]

Comment: Any way to display this information on Azure portal?..And can I get request count of hits to Traffic Manager?

Comment: Under **Overview** blade on Azure portal, you could find Status and Monitor status info.

Comment: Hey Fred, thank you for the prompt response...I have edited the post with snapshot.Can this status be logged somewhere? means at what time which endpoint Stopped /Inactive /was Online..Basically I want to monitor each and every activity of the endpoints and log them similar like we have Diagnostics for other Azure Components..

Comment: As far as I know, Azure portal does not provide built-in Logging feature for tracing and logging status of Traffic Manager.

Comment: Is there any way to trace the number of requests made to the traffic manager? I am using App Service as endpoints, so can I track how many requests are made to this AppService via TrafficManager?